# passing parameters to html select from php

Tags: php, html

I would like to pass php parameters to an html select options tag. it works fine for an input tag using the value attribute as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="to" value= "<?php echo $parameter ?>" size=10>
```

I tried to do the same for the select tag, but some reason its not working. Below is the select tag:

```
<select name="clinic">
    <option value="<?php echo $clinicName; ?>" >Baylor</option>
    <option value="<?php echo $clinicName; ?>" >IDCC</option>
</select>
```

Please note that the parameter would need to passed to an sql statement below these above statements as follows:

```
$clinicName = $_POST['clinic'];
$sql = "select * from patients where clinic = '$clinicName'";
```

Comment: What do you mean by PHP parameter? I take it that you have some database that is returning the values? Should work fine. Maybe you need to at some more code or be more precise.

Comment: *(suggested reading)* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain

Comment: Doesn't that code give you a select where all the options have the same value (i.e. what $clinicName contains)?

Comment: You need to loop over the possible values as currently you are just using the same clinic name twice.

Comment: One of the most confusing questions I've seen so far.  Anything you can do to clarify it would help greatly.

Comment: First, why do you want both options to have the same value? Second, what is the actual html that the browser gets? And you shouldn't use the data from `$_POST` directly in your sql, makes sql injection possible.

Comment: Please specify the error that you are getting, and at what point you are getting the error. Is it before or after submitting?

Comment: what is $clinicName in option value ?

Answer (score 0):

Should do the trick

```
<select name="clinic">
    <option <?php echo ($clinicName=="Baylor" ? "selected" : ""; ?> value="Baylor">Baylor</option>
    <option <?php echo ($clinicName=="IDCC" ? "selected" : ""; ?> value="IDCC">IDCC</option>
</select>
```

Also, as someone above me mentioned in the comments, you need to read up on SQLi otherwise your site is just one more to the list of already-hacked.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to set the current selected value on the `<select>`? If so, you need to use `if` statements to check which one to mark as selected:

```
<option value="Baylor"<?php if($clinicName == 'Baylor') echo ' "selected"'?>>Baylor</option>
<option value="IDCC"<?php if($clinicName == 'IDCC') echo ' "selected"'?>>IDCC</option>
```

Instead of the `if`, you could also use the [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

```
<option value="Baylor"<?php echo $clinicName == 'Baylor' ? ' "selected"' : ''?>>Baylor</option>
<option value="IDCC"<?php echo $clinicName == 'IDCC') ? ' "selected"' : ''?>>IDCC</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please sanitize your SQL query. Right now it is more exploitable than Lindsay Lohan. If you use mysql_* functions, then write it as:

```
$sql = "select * from patients where clinic = '".mysql_real_escape_string($clinicName)."'";
```

Secondly, in your HTML the $clinicName is the same on both cases. So the $_POST['clinic'] will always be the same no matter what. If you want to pre-select a value, then you need to write it as:

```
<select name="clinic">
    <option value="Baylor" <?php if($clinicName=='Baylor'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>>Baylor</option>
    <option value="IDCC" <?php if($clinicName=='IDCC'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>>IDCC</option>
</select>
```

Other than that, I remain a bit confused about your question.

Answer (score 0):

Copy this in your HTML tag

```
<select name="clinic">
<option value="baylor" >Baylor</option>
<option value="IDCC" >IDCC</option></select>
```

And this before your HTML tag

```
<?php 
echo $clinicName = $_POST['clinic'];
?>
```